# In which --- is it used for every wh-word?

Tags: pied-piping

I have learned that when we are using *which* if a word like *in* or *for* comes at the end of the *which* clause, we have to move those extra words to in front of the *which*  like this:

> The case for which the saint died was very religious.

What I am trying to ask is, does the same go with all the *wh*-words (*what, when, who, how,* etc.)?

There were some results with *whom*:

> We have clients for whom we provide only one small service.

If yes, please provide me with some example sentences. If not, please explain why only *which* is used for that type of case. Also, I am sorry for misusing any grammatical term if there was any.

Comment: I'm not sure which words you are referring to when you say "move those extra words in front of the 'which'". Do you mean "we have clients for whom" rather than "we have clients whom for"?

Comment: I edited it! And yes, what you assumed was very correct.

Comment: @toru Are you asking whether we really do need to move the preposition and the *wh-* word? If so, the answer is 'No!' See the linked-to question. But if you're asking whether we *can* move preposition phrases with different *wh-* words, not only with *which* and you also want to know which ones it's possible to do this with, that's a different question. In this case we probably need to have a little edit of the question and get it reopened.

Comment: I see a difference between asking under what circumstances a sentence can justifiably end in a preposition (as the question that this one is called a duplicate of does) and asking whether the rules for handling _which_ + preposition also apply to handling _what_ + preposition, _when_ + preposition, and _where_ + preposition (and perhaps also _why_ + preposition and _whether_ + preposition). The question is based on what I take to be a false supposition that there is a strict rule for handling _which_ + preposition; but beyond that, it seems to me to be a question not previously asked at EL&U.